# Mongoose for product system with different attributes depending on product type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a small product system to try and get me into Node.js, Mongo and the like.
I was drawn to Mongo for the possibilities of storing products of different types in the same collection instead of having multiple tables, eav or any of the other MySQL-methods that didn't quite fit.

I was reading through tutorials and at first fell over writing a Provider for the ProductModel, but then someone suggested i should use Mongoose.

However, the issue with Mongoose seems to be that i need a set schema for each model. My first idea was that a product should have a `title` and a `type` attribute. Then `type` would decide the overall product structure. So for example a `dvd` product might have a director while a `t-shirt` product would not have a director but would have different sizes.

Is it possible to implement this kind of structure in Mongoose, and how? It's my understanding that if i provide a schema for each produt type i won't be able to query them simultaneously? Does different schemas mean different collection? -  I couldn't quite figure that out.

Any help and guidance is appreciated, would like to be able to use a framework instead of writing the DB handling myself (although that what was i planning to do initially, but if someone else allready did it better than me :))

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has a schemaless type which can be very useful in your case, but might not be the best solution.

ProductSchema = new Schema({any: {}});

If you change anything on this object you need to notify Mongoose about it with obj.markModified('field-name') before saving.

My suggestion is to use your own wrapper over [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), which I'm running on production for 7~8 months without problems.

There's another lib called [mongous](https://github.com/amark/mongous) that you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it seems that Mongoose Schemas aren't strict unless you tell them to be. And when you use Mongoose.model you can apparently define what collection it is to be used on. Combine that with inheritance i think i have what i'm looking for.